# android, how to use mockk to mock BuildConfig.DEBUG

Tags: mockk, android-unit-testing

using mockk for unit test, and would like to mock the BuilConfig.DEBUG.

```
        io.mockk.mockkObject(BuildConfig::class) // or mockkStatic
        io.mockk.every { BuildConfig.DEBUG } returns true //<=== throws
```

but it throws exception

```
Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock
```

How to mock the BuildConfig.DEBUG using mockk?

Comment: It is best to wrap those kind of stuffs. https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/107#issuecomment-456325979

Comment: looking for native mokk solution. besides there is some functionalities controlled by code that are in 3rd part lib and cannt change the code there.